# Binding multiple HTML properties using WinJS?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

WinJS allows you to bind HTML properties dynamically at run-time, similar to XAML binding.

```
<div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template"...>
    <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: timestamp"></h3>
</div>
```

How if I want to also bind the font color style for `<h3>` as well, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the `data-win-options` binding which makes use of `{key:value,key2:value2}` syntax. `data-win-binding` uses a syntax similar to inline-css styles.

Using `property:bindingValue;property2:bindingValue2` etc will allow you bind multiple properties to the same HTML control.

As an example to answer the question above:

```
<div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template"...>
     <h3 data-win-bind="style.color: fontcolor; innerText: timestamp"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, you use binding initializers, of the form: "foo: bar My.Custom.Function". Take a look at WinJS.Binding.converter for a helper/wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you want to switch between green and red color if the timestamp is "important", and you have a field "isImportant" in your model:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: timestamp; style.color: isImportant MyConverters.colorConverter"></h3> </div>
```

Then you could use an converter to return the preferred color depending on the boolean isImportant like this:

**JS:**

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyConverters", {
    //Converter function
    colorConverter: WinJS.Binding.converter(function (important) {
        return important ? "Green" : "Red";
    })
});
```

Comment: I wonder how bind to `style['background-image']` property? Because in css it will use `url` function, ie. `background-image: url('http://myurl.com/image.jpg')` but how do I apply this `url()` inside of binding?