# How can I databind the label of a WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand?

Tags: winjs

With Visual Studio 2012 I created a JavaScript Blank App, added a global variable in js/default.js:

```
var mylabel = "my label";
```

and I called

```
WinJS.Binding.processAll();
```

at the end of app.onactivated.

Then I added two AppBarCommands in default.html:

```
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
    data-win-bind="label: mylabel">
</button>
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
    data-win-bind="innerText: mylabel">
</button>
```

The first binding does nothing, the second one shows the text "my label" instead of the button. How can I databind the button label ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the label property of the app bar command control instance. This can be done with:

```
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
    data-win-bind="winControl.label: mylabel">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found in the answer of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097998/binding-multiple-html-properties-using-winjs) that I can use:

```
data-win-options="{label: mylabel}"
```

But it doesn't work if I have a ListView with an itemtemplate that contains an AppBarCommand, and I want to databind to a List.